# Bluetooth: Trouble creating a SCO connection, receiving limited resources error

Tags: bluetooth

I am currently trying to establish a SCO connection to a phone. I am able to successfully establish the connection with the link manager and establish an ACL link. I have tried various settings for both voice and packet type but have had no change in the message that I am receiving. Currently I have the packet type set to allow all pack types

From what I've gathered (from google searches and on here) is that the limited resources error is typically received when T2 settings are sent to a T1-only listener. I have been unable to find any reference in the core 4.2 documentation or through google search as to what T1 and T2 settings are. If anyone could provide any information it would be greatly appreciated. I am currently writing for a bluetooth module BM81SPK02MG from ISSC